# Select MAX value with restriction to rows

Tags: mysql, sum

I have 3 tables:

matchdays:

```
matchday_id | season_id | userid | points | matchday
----------------------------------------------------
1           |  1        | 1      | 33     | 1
2           |  1        | 2      | 45     | 1
etc
```

players

```
userid | username
-----------------
1      | user1
2      | user2
etc.
```

seasons

```
seasons_id  | title  | userid
----------------------------
1           | 2011   | 3
2           | 2012   | 10
3           | 2013   | 5
```

My query:

```
SELECT s.title, p.username, SUM(points) FROM matchdays m
INNER JOIN players p ON p.userid = m.userid
INNER JOIN seasons s ON m.userid = s.userid
group by s.season_id
```

This results in (example!):

```
title | username | SUM(points)
------------------------------
2011  | user3    | 3744
2012  | user10   | 3457
2013  | user5    | 3888
```

What it should look like is a table with the winner (max points) of every season. Right now, the title and username is correct, but the sum of the points is way too high. I couldn't figure out what sum is calculated. Ideally, the sum is the addition of every matchday of a season for every user.

Comment: Did you try SUM(m.points)?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: could you explain why there's a userid in the season table? Doesnt make sense to me. You have to show more different data for us to understand your structure

Comment: @mcriecken yes, exactly the same result.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: That group by will give you the total points for all users in the season. You probably want to group by both season and user

Comment: @ThomasG Because I have to manually add the winner of the season to the season table. I know that this is a big flaw in the script/db and I'm working on having it calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you group by seasons only. Thus your SUM is running on all points over a season, regardless of the player.

The whole approach is wrong anyway. The "flaw" with userid in the season table is your biggest issue, and you seem to know it.
I will explain you how to calculate your rankings in the database one time for all, and to have them at your disposal at all times, which will save you a lot of headaches, and obviously save some CPU and loading times as well.

### Start by creating a new table "Rankings":

```
CREATE table rankings (season_id INT, userid INT, points INT, rank INT)
```

If you have a lot of players, index all columns but `points`

### Then, populate the table for each season:

This is a oneshot operation to run each time a season has ended. 
So for the time being, you will have to run it several times for each season.

The key here is to compute the **rank** of each player for the season, which is a must-have that will be super-handy for later.  Because MySQL doesnt have a window function for that, we have to use an old trick  : incrementing a counter.

I decompose.

This will compute the points of a season, and provide the ranking for that season:

```
SELECT season_id, userid, SUM(points) as points 
FROM matchdays
WHERE season_id = 1
GROUP BY season_id, userid
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Now we adapt this query to add a rank column :

```
SELECT
   season_id, userid, points,
   @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM
(   
    SELECT season_id, userid, SUM(points) as points 
    FROM matchdays
    WHERE season_id = 1
    GROUP BY season_id, userid
)   T, 
(
    SELECT @curRank := 0
) R
ORDER BY T.points DESC
```

That's it.
Now we can INSERT the results of this computation into our ranking table, to store it once for good :

```
INSERT INTO rankings
SELECT
   season_id, userid, points,
   @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM
(   
    SELECT season_id, userid, SUM(points) as points 
    FROM matchdays
    WHERE season_id = 1
    GROUP BY season_id, userid
)   T, 
(
    SELECT @curRank := 0
) R
ORDER BY T.points DESC
```

Change the `season_id = 1` and repeat for each season.
Save this query somewhere, and in the future, run it once each time  a season has ended.

Now you have a proper database-computed ranking and a nice ranking table that you can query whenever you want.

You want the winner for each season ? As simple as that:

```
SELECT S.title, P.username, R.points
FROM Ranking R
INNER JOIN seasons S ON R.season_id=S.season_id
INNER JOIN players P ON R.userid=P.userid
WHERE R.rank = 1
```

You will discover over the time that you can do a lot of different things very simply with your ranking table.

Comment: Thank you so much! This totally solves everything!

For those who are interested, here are the little changes I had to make:

Line 15: Added "desc". Otherwise the table would be upside down. Winner at last rank.

Query:
Line 1: P.Username
Little typo at Line 2: rankings R

Again, thank you very much Thomas!

Comment: I did +1 of course ;) but my reputation ist too low so my vote is not public :(

Answer (score 0):

You're join is wrong, try something like:

```
SELECT  s.title, p.username, SUM(m.points) as points FROM matchdays m
JOIN players p ON p.userid = m.userid
JOIN seasons s ON m.season_id = s.season_id
group by s.season_id, p.userid
ORDER by points DESC;
```

As pointed out, userid does'nt belong/is not needed in 'seasons' table.

Comment: Your SQL will fail on sql_mode=only_full_group_by because you use GROUP BY incorrect read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/