# mysql sum top 5 scores per player and put in ranking

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a ranking with the best 5 scores of the players summed and put in a ranking. Players have more or less then 5 scores.

For now I have the following query:

```
set @count:=0, @player:=''; 
SELECT SEIZOEN
     , WEDSTRIJDTYPE
     , ATLEET_ID
     , GROEP_NAAM
     , GROEP_OMS
     , SUM(PUNTEN_WC) as WC_RESULT 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT ATLEET_ID
            , PUNTEN_WC
            , SEIZOEN
            , WEDSTRIJDTYPE
            , GROEP_NAAM
            , GROEP_OMS     
         FROM 
            ( SELECT PUNTEN_WC
                   , SEIZOEN
                   , WEDSTRIJDTYPE
                   , GROEP_NAAM
                   , GROEP_OMS
                   , @count := if (@player != ATLEET_ID,0,@count + 1) as count
                   , @player := ATLEET_ID as ATLEET_ID  
                FROM 
                   ( SELECT ATLEET_ID
                          , PUNTEN_WC
                          , k.SEIZOEN
                          , k.WEDSTRIJDTYPE
                          , g.GROEP_NAAM
                          , g.GROEP_OMS 
                       FROM RESULTATEN r 
                       LEFT 
                       JOIN KALENDER k 
                         ON r.KALENDER_ID = k.KALENDER_ID
                       JOIN GROEP_SNB g 
                         ON r.GROEP_NAAM = g.GROEP_NAAM
                       JOIN SKIER s 
                         ON r.ATLEET_ID = s.SKIER_ID
                      WHERE k.WEDSTRIJDTYPE = 'Dutch Cup snowboard '  
                        AND k.SEIZOEN = '2016-2017'    
                      order 
                         by ATLEET_ID
                          , PUNTEN_WC DESC          
                   ) x
            ) y   
        where count < 6
     ) z  
 GROUP 
    BY ATLEET_ID 
 ORDER 
    BY GROEP_NAAM
     , WC_RESULT DESC 
 LIMIT 0,2000;
```

The  problem is this query doesn't take the five best scores of each player.

When I run the most inner query it's sorts the scores fine.

```
SELECT ATLEET_ID
     , PUNTEN_WC
     , k.SEIZOEN
     , k.WEDSTRIJDTYPE
     , g.GROEP_NAAM
     , g.GROEP_OMS 
  FROM RESULTATEN r 
  LEFT 
  JOIN KALENDER k 
    ON r.KALENDER_ID = k.KALENDER_ID 
  JOIN GROEP_SNB g 
    ON r.GROEP_NAAM = g.GROEP_NAAM
  JOIN SKIER s 
    ON r.ATLEET_ID = s.SKIER_ID
 WHERE k.WEDSTRIJDTYPE = 'Dutch Cup snowboard '  
   AND k.SEIZOEN = '2016-2017'    
 order 
    by ATLEET_ID
     , PUNTEN_WC DESC
```

I've put a count on the records so I can limit it to best of 5. But then the trouble starts. With the second query the highscores are still ordered correctly but the count-field is not 0 to 5?

So when I put the third query in it stops when count-field is 5, but I want a maximum of 5 scores per player.

Comment: You might find some inspiration on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761690/select-max-value-with-restriction-to-rows/43764408#43764408) I posted yesterday. This is the same functional issue has you have, computing rankings efficiently from a match table.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Note that k is an inner join

Comment: @ThomasG Thank you. You're example takes all the results per season of the player. I only need the best 5 scores. Am I correct?

Comment: If you make a ranking table, you have all scores per seasons. Thus you can select easily any ranks you want for any season... The winner, the podium, the top 5...

Comment: @ThomasG I need the best 5 scores per player per season summed up in one score. So player 1 has scored in 1 season 5+20+15+10+30+40. His top 5 scores will be 40+30+20+15+10=115. This score I want to use to make a ranking of all players in 1 season. I hope you understand me... ;-)

Comment: @B.Cleanfield: please take the addendum material that was deleted 22 hours ago from an answer, and edit it into your question. Or, if it is essentially a different question, please post a new question rather than changing this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can sum the top N values for each person with this query:

Creating a simple test table and populating it -

```
CREATE TABLE Scores
    (`id` int, `playerName` varchar(16), `score` int)
;

INSERT INTO Scores
    (`id`, `playerName`, `score`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Joe', 5),
    (2, 'Joe', 5),
    (3, 'Joe', 5),
    (4, 'Joe', 1),
    (5, 'Joe', 10),
    (6, 'Joe', 10),
    (7, 'Joe', 15),
    (8, 'Bob', 5),
    (9, 'Bob', 5),
    (10, 'Bob', 2),
    (11, 'Bob', 10),
    (12, 'Bob', 3),
    (13, 'Bob', 10),
    (14, 'Bob', 20)
;
```

The query:

```
SET @score_rank := 0;
SET @current_player  = '';
SET @topN = 5;
Select playerName, SUM(score)
From (Select playerName, score,
        @score_rank := IF(@current_player = playerName, (@score_rank + 1), 1) AS score_rank,
        @current_player := playerName
      From Scores 
      Order By playerName, score DESC) sorted
Where score_rank <= @topN
Group By playerName;
```

The inner query assigns values to two variables - `@current_player` and `@score_rank`.  If the `@current_player` value matches `playerName`, it increments `@score_rank`, otherwise it sets the `@score_rank` to 1.  By doing this, we can grab only the top 5 for each player.  The outer query then sums those top 5 scores.  You can change the value of `@topN` if you want to sum a different set (like top 10).

Results with the above sample table:

```
playerName  SUM(score)
----------  ----------
Bob         50
Joe         45
```

See it here: http://rextester.com/CLO11640

Comment: You created one table, then inserted into another. Was that deliberate?

Comment: @Strawberry Nope - fixed it.  I probably changed the name testing and didn't fix it before posting.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was pretty much a duplicate of another answer.